# Reload the page when I switch to another tab and come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, reload

I have used the below Javascript code.

```
$(window).focus(function () {
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Which was called in `focus` event. But whenever I switch or click on some other application or desktop tab, it's started reloading. I need it to be reloaded only when I switch over tabs not when I clicked somewhere other than a browser.

Comment: You'd have better to describe why would you need this kind of behaviour... [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

See Arthik, 
If my understanding is correct - you need to take OR give some ID for the TAB control
and modify your code as :

```
$(#tabID).focus(function () {
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```

tabID - is the ID of you Tab control ( or the DIV -as you are using )

if mistaken - pls Update your query for our better understanding